# Unable to add blocks in wordpress posts

Tags: block-editor

When I was making wordpress posts earlier, I would click on add new and a new post would be created. There would
be a plus sign and by clicking on the plus sign, I would be able to add blocks.

Somehow, I am not able to add blocks now and am presented with this screen instead.

[image]

Even the plus sign on the top left is not working. What am I doing wrong ?

Please do note that I installed the classics editor and then Uninstalled it. This problem has been happening ever since then. Could the uninstalled classics editor be the culprit somehow?

Comment: your editor is in code/text mode, possibly because you turned it off in your profile edit screen, possibly because you selected code editor in the options menu, or because a plugin has triggered a JS error and the block editor didn't finish loading. I would also remove the `admin` user and change all passwords on that site as posting login details means it's now severely compromised. I'm editing it out but it's been online for 32 minutes so it's too late to rely on stack exchange redaction

Comment: to reiterate, sharing the login of an adminstrator account publicly is extremely dangerous

Comment: @TomJNowell , I was anyway going to reset wordpress and delete everything ...The issue got fixed.. thanks. I unchecked "Disable the visual editor when writing" and it solved the problem. Now, I am facing another problem

Comment: it doesn't matter if that was your plan, someone could have used those credentials to put things on your site that a database reset would not clear, enough time has already passed to have done things your host would terminate your account for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your editor is in code/text mode.

It's possibly this is because you turned it off in your profile edit screen.

Its also possible it's because you selected code editor in the options menu in the top right corner.

[image]

It's also possible you have JS errors in your browser console that are preventing the block editor from loading.

> Please do note that I installed the classics editor and then Uninstalled it. This problem has been happening ever since then. Could the uninstalled classics editor be the culprit somehow?

No, the classic editor would need to be installed and active to interfere with the block editor.